# Is it true that the paragraph in Tree Menu of MSDN library is store in the database?

Tags: asp.net, database, menu, tree, msdn

I was assigned to develop a website looks similar to [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/default.aspx).

According to MSDN Library, I have sense that their tree menu is updated in the database. They are not fixed like others Javascript tree menu. But I am not sure, I just have doubt, is it true that the paragraph in Tree Menu of MSDN library is store in the database? If it's true, respectfully, may you please provide me a brief explanation of MSDN library database diagram? I really appreciate for all the contributor in StackOverFlow and looking forward for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sort of true, the following is from [Scott Hanselman's blog discussing msdn](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/LowBandwidthViewAndOtherHiddenAndFutureFeaturesOfMSDN.aspx):

> I figured there can't just be the
>   (loband) "switch" and I mentioned I
>   thought that having to hack the URL
>   was kind of wonky. Turns out that the
>   whole MSDN system isn't a bunch of
>   files on disk, but files in a database
>   with an ASP.NET Virtual Path Provider.
>   Tim Ewald wrote about how they did
>   this WAY back in February of 2005.
>   This was, at the time, kind of a
>   poor-man's ASP.NET Routing:
>
> The normalized path points to a file
>   that does not exist on disk. Rather,
>   the page data is stored in the content
>   cache. The system uses a
>   VirtualPathProvider (VPP) to bridge
>   the gap between the two. In essence, a
>   VPP intercepts all of the ASP.NET
>   plumbing's requests for file streams
>   and gives you a chance to load them
>   from wherever you like. Every ASP.NET
>   app uses a default VPP that simply
>   maps to the file system. An MTPS-based
>   site registers a custom
>   VirtualPathProvider, which sits in
>   front of the default VPP, forming a
>   chain. The custom VPP uses the
>   DocumentInfo and ContentSet objects
>   that the HTTP module's
>   OnPreResolveRequestCache event handler
>   stored in HTTP context to load a topic
>   from the content cache and return it
>   as an .aspx file stream.

And if you want to know more about how MSDN is built have a look at the [linked article from Tim Ewald](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163845.aspx)